# Limited return value from python to php

Tags: php, python, python-3.x

I am calling the python script from php using the following command

```
$url = "https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-your-redis-installation-on-ubuntu-14-04";
$output = shell_exec('python PythonScripts/readable.py '.$url);
echo($output);
```

When I run the file using commandline

```
python extractor.py https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-your-redis-installation-on-ubuntu-14-04
```

I am getting the desired output.

The contents of python file are

```
import sys
from readability.readability import Document
from urllib import FancyURLopener

class MyOpener(FancyURLopener):
    version = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; it; rv:1.8.1.11)'

myopener = MyOpener()
request = myopener.open(sys.argv[1])
html = request.read()

readable_article = Document(html).summary()
readable_title = Document(html).short_title()

print readable_article #If I use readable_title then it's getting printed in php
```

The problem is that `readable_article` is not captured by php. But when I use command line both `readable_article` and `readable_title` are printed out.

What can be the issue? I tried with `exec(), system()` and still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple issues:

- Different user's (execution permissions for the python script)
- Fullpath to python interpreter and script ('/usr/bin/python ~/PythonScripts/readable.py')
- ...

You could use [popen](http://php.net/manual/de/function.popen.php) instead of shell_exec, to make debugging easier. That results in numeric return value, stdout and stderr.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the issue. The problem was that the python script was giving out the error

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2014' in position 3102: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I fixed the issue by using either one of the below
`readable_article = Document(html).summary().encode('utf8')`
`readable_article = Document(html).summary().encode('ascii', 'replace')`